# Logging: How to set the newline character of log files?

Tags: python, logging, newline, eol, os-agnostic

I'm using logging on **Python** 3.7+ on both **Windows** and **Linux**, yet the line ending depends on the platform.

While you can set the newline character when reading or writing a file, obviously you cannot when setting a `logging.FileHandler` :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler

Something like `logging.FileHandler(newline = '\n')` would do, as in `io.open(newline = '\n')` :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file#io.open (reading or writing files)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file#io.TextIOWrapper (`newline` explained here)

Perhaps there is a way to ensure the same line ending for logging on both **Windows** and **Linux**, but I found none yet.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't have control over that, because `open()` which the FileHandler uses under the hood replaces newlines with the OS default. If you really want specific control over it, to create newlines that are different from the current OS default you have to subclass the FileHandler:

```
import logging

class MyFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def _open(self):
        return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding, newline='\n') # set newline according to your needs here

h = MyFileHandler("foo.log")
```

edit: removed `errors` which didn't exist in 3.7

Comment: Hi, seems a good solution yet I get : `AttributeError: 'MyFileHandler' object has no attribute 'errors'`

Comment: @Kochise errors is new in python 3.9 I removed it so the code will work with 3.7

Comment: Indeed that did it and it works, it's a bit strange to go that way just to override a hidden parameter.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler

Answer (score 2):

`logging.FileHandler` inherits from `logging.StreamHandler` which has a `terminator` attribute. You may set it on the instance. I've provided a portable solution using the `os` module, but you may set it explicitly if desired.

```py
import logging
h = logging.FileHandler("foo.log")
h.terminator = "\n"
```

**edit**: Fixed solution to always use `\n` as the line terminator.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler.terminator

Comment: Ok, I already tried `h.terminator = '\n'` but the line ending still is `\r\n` on **Windows**.

Comment: @Kochise: `\r\n` is the correct line terminator for Windows text files. It probably doesn't do that on Lunix.